# Timeseries chart of land classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart

reusing some code i created this project to display the histogram of soil classes:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6e9a7f17f4ae0260f796727c4d4f3e1a

The image has only one band and pixel values ​​that correspond to a specific class.

Now, using a collection with the same image for different years, I'd like to create a chart showing the variation for each individual class over time.

I searched for timeseries examples but I can't find examples similar to my case.

I try to start from this code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7c0a120682668a306d05a38dca6d3123

The code shows the chart with the number of pixels for each image in the collection but I would like to distinguish it by class as in the previous example

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map `ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram` over the image collection to get a histogram per year as a feature collection and then use `ui.Chart.feature.byProperty` to plot the results as a chart. You might need to do a bit of formatting of the x axis labels to get them in the order you want.

```js
var imgCol = ee.ImageCollection('users/danielepiccolo/consumo_suolo/CS_ARPAV')
  .select('b1');

var region = ee.FeatureCollection('users/danielepiccolo/Shapefile/Veneto');

var histCol = ee.FeatureCollection(imgCol.map(function(img) {
  var hist = img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: 10,
    maxPixels: 1e13
  });
  return ee.Feature(null, hist.get('b1')).copyProperties(img, ['anno']);
})).filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['anno']));


var xProps = histCol.first()
  .propertyNames().filter(ee.Filter.neq('item', 'anno'));

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byProperty({
  features: histCol,
  xProperties: xProps,
  seriesProperty: 'anno'
}).setOptions({
  title: 'Class histogram per year',
  hAxis: {
    title: 'Class',
  },
  vAxis: {
    title: 'Frequency',
  }
});
print(chart);
```

You can also convert the image collection into a stack of bands in a single image and then use `ui.Chart.image.histogram` to plot the histogram per year. This method is sort of expecting continuous variables, so the autogenerated x axis labels are bin ranges, instead of discrete class labels.

```
var imgCol = ee.ImageCollection('users/danielepiccolo/consumo_suolo/CS_ARPAV')
  .select('b1')
  .filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['anno']));

var region = ee.FeatureCollection('users/danielepiccolo/Shapefile/Veneto');

imgCol = imgCol.map(function(img) {
  var bname = img.getNumber('anno').format('%.0f');
  return img.rename(bname).set('bname', bname);
});

var bnames = imgCol.aggregate_array('bname');

var img = imgCol.toBands().rename(bnames);

var chart = ui.Chart.image.histogram({
  image: img, region: region, scale: 10, maxPixels: 1e13})
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Class histogram per year',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Class',
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Frequency',
    }
  });

print(chart);
```

Comment: Braten , Very helpfull, thank you very much.